# The asset xxx is not present in the asset pipeline - Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I am struggling with a problem. I migrated my app from rails 6 + webpacker to rails 7 + jsbundling + webpack following this tutorial : https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/main/docs/switch_from_webpacker.md

However, I get this error "The asset 'transportation_calculator.js' is not present in the asset pipeline" everytime I access a page.

Here is my manifest.json :

```
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .scss

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../builds
```

In my application.html.erb I have :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

And I start the haml page that I'm trying to load with:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'transportation_calculator.js'
```

Thank you very much for you help !

I tried to change the path in webpack.config.js to :

```
  entry: {
    // add your css or sass entries
    application: [
      './app/javascript/application.js',
      './app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss',
    ],
  }
```

without success. The error remained the same.

Comment: where exactly is `transportation_calculator.js`?

Comment: it's in app/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'transportation_calculator.js' %>
```

When you do this in your template `rails` and `sprockets` will try to find that file in the asset path. Because you're using `jsbundling-rails` "app/javascript" is not one of these paths:

```rb
>> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> 
["/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/builds",
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/config",
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/images",
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/stylesheets",
...
```

When you run `bin/dev` webpack will compile `app/javascript/application.js` and save it into `app/assets/builds/application.js` this is the file that's being loaded with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

What you need to do is to import your file in `application.js`:

```
// app/javascript/application.js

import "./transportation_calculator"
```

---

If you actually, don't want `webpack` to compile anything, you can add `app/assets/javascripts` directory that will be loaded only with `sprockets`:

```bash
app/
└── assets/
    └── javascripts/
        └── transportation_calculator.js
```

Make sure to precompile it:

```js
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//...
//= link_tree ../javascripts .js
```

Now you can load that file directly with
`javascript_include_tag "transportation_calculator"`